# How to get the Instagram comments API Url and what is media id?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to perform load more operation in instagram comments for the particular image.?
And also i would like to know about MEDIA-ID, and how to use the api-id in API?

Answer (score 3):

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/Media_id/comments?access_token=YourAccessToken

check this.....

```
caption{
created_time: "1400758793",
text: "Key",
from: {
username: "",
profile_picture: "",
id: "1303077801",
full_name: ""
},
id: "725939832520166364"
},
user_has_liked: false,
id: "**725939832058792529_1303077801**",// this media id
```

Comment: But here i am getting all comments.I want to perform load more. Like i have to  load first 10 comments.then again i have to load  10 more comments...